# 301 Redirect in ASP.NET web.config including Parameters

Tags: asp.net, redirect, url-rewriting, web-config

I'm looking into using 301 redirects having noticed a bunch of hits on my domain on Google Analytics to .asp pages which not longer exist having moved everything over to a .NET setup.

Having spent a bit of time Googling, I have been able to add the following code to my web.config.

```
<location path="products.asp">
    <system.webServer>
     <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://www.hartnollguitars.co.uk/products.aspx" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

This is fine and moves everything from `products.asp` to `pproducts.aspx` but it does not preserve the querystring, which is essential to make any sense, ie `products.aspx?id=789`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add  `$Q` to the destination url to preserve the querystring.
So in your case it should look like this:

```
<location path="products.asp">
    <system.webServer>
     <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://www.hartnollguitars.co.uk/products.aspx$Q" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have IIS 7 or greater, there is a far more robust solution to URL rewrites. Using the [URL Rewrite Module 2.0](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite), you can create rich redirects that can include the original query string. Following this [guide on IIS.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819774/301-redirect-in-asp-net-web-config-including-parameters), you can see in the screenshot the "Append query string" option. [image: IIS URL Rewrite Module UI]

You also have the option of using the server variable {QUERY_STRING}. Finally, if you used a Regex with groups in your rule's pattern, you can use the variables {R:#} as shown in the screenshot as well.

Comment: Thanks Adam,but I'm on a share server so don't have full access.